# PowerPoint document pulls data points from XML / Excel

Tags: xml, excel, powerpoint

What I want to do:

Pull information (numbers, words, etc) from fields that are either in an XML document or in an Excel spreadsheet, and embed these values in a text paragraph inside of a PowerPoint presentation.

Example:

> Yearly, the production of product Y
>   has reached <###> thousand units.

where <###> is some value pulled from the XML or Excel document.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand your response correctly, I would have to parse every slide to look through for the string "Yearly, the production of product Y has reached 5245" (as example) and then replace the substring "5245" programatically with the more accurate variable that is contained in the XML document?

I was looking for a way where I could flag a text box with some variable name, have an XML document with coordinating variables, and have some code that pushes the information from the element in the XML into the TextBox with the appropriate variable name...

Comment: just wanted to check in with you to see if the answer below answered your question.

Comment: Not really, but I appreciate the response.  I actually don't need to do this but I figured if someone stumbled upon this and commented it might help someone else.  I appear to have lost "points", should I have closed this post or something and am being penalized?

Comment: I've moved to close it as based on not needing an answer anymore, it is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if this is possible or how exactly to do it? This is certainly possible, but a little "hacky" in that ever single <####> would need to be actively managed (for example you would need program against slide and object the sentence "Yearly, the production of product Y has reached <###> thousand units." exists on and then look for that pattern and insert what you need from XML or Excel.